# Из for в foreach

Tags: c#

```
string[] wNames = ...
for (int i = 0; i < wNames.Length; i++)
{
   wNames[i] = wNames[i].Substring(wNames[i].LastIndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
}
```

Как данный пример перевести в foreach ?
У меня не получается, пишет что невозможно присвоить `wNames[i] =`

Comment: `foreach (string wNm in wNames) {wNm = ...}` ?

Comment: @MBo, вот я так и пробовал, говорит что невозможно присвоить, так-как является циклом foreach

Comment: внутри `foreach` нельзя менять элементы коллекции

Comment: и чем вам не подходит `for`?

Comment: А, понятно, итератор возвращает локальную переменную, которую изменять смысла нет, вот компилятор и помогает, подсказывая, что так нельзя делать.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov, да я просто хотел перевести в linq это всё в одну строчку, но оно не даётся, попробовал через foreach провести но тоже минус, походу остаётся только так

Comment: @MBo, не, там не про смысл, а про ее константность, сам компилятор ругается.

Comment: @ZidoX, linq не предназначен для `in-place` замены элементов. Ты можешь с помощью Select получить новую коллекцию с нужными элементами и проблемы с присваиванием не будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда ты используешь цикл `foreach`, ты не получаешь доступ к адресу ячеек массива, а извлекаешь только значения.

Для того чтобы изменять данные в массиве стоит использовать обычный цикл `for`. Если ты нуждаешься только в чтении данных из массива, то можно использовать `for` или `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

С использованием `Linq` будет выглядеть практически так же на вид, только вообще без цикла и без индекса, потому что обрабатываются сразу все элементы массива:

```cs
wNames = wNames.Select(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(':') + 1).Trim()).ToArray();
```

А с помощью `foreach` поменять не получится, ну, это уже объяснили.